# Who do you think provides good answers and how could we learn from their answers?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

I've actually noticed my answers sometimes either come off as snarky or long winded when I review them(if they are, tell me. I like learning about my weaknesses) and I was curious what makes a person good at giving answers?

I know I posted an answer to a question in meta awhile ago about HOW to give good answers, but now I'm looking for what the community WANTS as good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer:

- those with the highest reputation score

But in addition to that, you can be even more specific - who has the highest rep in the tag you are interested in, or the highest rep per post

That's really the only way to answer your headline question :-)

Comment: So TL;DR: The bears nearly always?